# how to create reoccurring schedule of firebase notification composer

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-predictions

with new option of prediction and audience targeting of notification in firebase notification composer, I want to be able to target churn users as soon as they join the churn group with a notification and re schedule it so it will happen every time from now until the end of year. So I do not want the same user to receive the same notification over and over again , just once when user become churn.  how is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

This is currently a tricky use-case, since there's no built-in knowledge of when a user enters or exits the group. We're considering making this easier by either triggering Cloud Functions based on enter/exit of a group and/or handling the criteria in the platform (FCM and Predictions) directly. But as usual: while we'd love to add those features, there are no guarantees that it will happen nor a ballpark on when.

Comment: A function that get triggered would be nice if I could call a notification composer item to be sent for the user. So my marketing can manage the push with the firebase interface notification composer. Since it does not exist I need to basically create a composer of my self which is not preferred